# Add New Group - Access Denied error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We have a really strange problem.

My userid is a farm administrator and it a site collection admin on the site in question.

If I add a new group (to manage permissions), once I click the OK button on the create group page I get thrown to the **Error: Access Denied** page.

Here's the strange part, the ***group gets created***.

If I try to add a user to that group, I get the access denied page but the user is not put in the group.

If I try to delete the group I get an error page that says **Cannot complete this action. Please try again**.

It appears to be only happening on this one site (and it's sub-sites).

There is nothing in any of the sharepoint logs or the event logs.

It has got to be a permission problem but I don't know what.

**EDIT ------------------------------------ EDIT**

After some more research I found [this BLOG post](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/HTTP-403-Forbidden-in-a-SharePoint-site-when-adding-members.aspx). It states that a .NET 2.0
hotfix is the culprit of the problem and states that removing it will fix the problem.

I can't removed the hotfix because it is not installed.

**Are we doomed to be stuck with this problem?**

**END EDIT**

Comment: Have you tried it with a user created within that site as an admin. ie. a brand new user for that site. If that works, then the id you use currently may be the problem.

Comment: It has been tried by more than one person who has Farm admin permissions. I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at.

Comment: What I mean is that you can control access on a Site by Site basis. Create a new user dedicated to that site that is not attached to AD and give it god rights. I'm trying to troubleshoot whether its an AD or a SharePoint issue. If my idea works then AD groups are to blame and if not, Sharepoint is.

Comment: Are groups in SharePoint tied to groups in SharePoint? I'm trying to create a group in SharePoint.

Comment: Do you mean "are groups in SharePoint tied to Active Directory?" The answer is no but they can be.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe one of the system pages in _layouts has wacky permissions on it.  Look in the IIS logs (not SharePoint logs) for a 401, 403 or 407 (or really, any HTTP code above 400) error for your user around the time you try to add/delete a group.  This might point to the page that is having the problem, which will give you something to go on.

Answer (score 0):

if you host your sharepoint web applications somewhere other than the default location that IIS/SP uses; check to ensure that the Users group has read to the Bin directory of the affected application. For some reason when this particular app was created it failed to add the Users group to the Bin directory with Read as it normally would under normal circumstances. This is easily testable and fails and succeeds with consistency.  the only thing I've noted that it affected was the issue regarding adding New Users to a site through the Sharepoint site GUI.

This is the error received when digging through my SP logs:

Application error when access /_layouts/aclinv.aspx, Error=Access to the path 'D:\ProdSites\SP-ProdSites*****\bin' is denied.   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)     at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String path, String userPathOriginal, String searchPattern, Boolean includeFiles, Boolean includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption)     at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)     at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(String searchPattern)     at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()     at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)     at System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal()     at...

This is the error I was showing in the IIS logs:

2009-09-09 13:48:19 W3SVC1237373898  IP GET /OOD/_layouts/aclinv.aspx GroupId=9&Source=http%INFO2Fpeople%2Easpx%3FMembershipGroupId%3D9 80 domain\user IP Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+OfficeLiveConnector.1.4;+OfficeLivePatch.1.3;+86e) 403 0 0

maybe people have already checked this but it took me a bit. I looked for patch KB928365 and it wasn't present (lots of other posts are recommending the removal of this patch to fix this issue). 
Also, the behavior was different in QA and Production as the acct I was using to add New Users to the site in QA had elevated priviledge due to its inclusion in the WSS_admin_wpg group (possibly due to the fact that its a farm admin in QA?)